# Spring pendulum system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

> Find the Lagrangian and the equations of motion for the system described by the figure using the Lagrange multipliers method. The mass $m$ can slide frictionless along the massless rigid rod of the pendulum $M$. The spring is wrapped around the rigid rod and is connected to the mass $m$. The pendulum $M$ is not connected to the spring. The spring constant is $k$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]. What is _your_ question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I see the 'use' of a Lagrange multiplier in this question, I don't really see the 'need' for it, so let's make it a little simpler.

The Lagrangian for this system is found from:

$$ T = \frac{1}{2}[M(r_1\dot\theta)^2 + m_2(\dot{r_2}^2 +(r_2\dot\theta)^2)]  $$

$$ V = -(Mr_1+mr_2)g\cos\theta + \frac{1}{2}k(r_2-l_0)^2$$

$$ L = \frac{1}{2}[M(r_1\dot\theta)^2 + m_2(\dot{r_2}^2 +(r_2\dot\theta)^2)] + (Mr_1+mr_2)g\cos\theta - \frac{1}{2}k(r_2-l_0)^2 $$

Where $l_0$ is the initial length of the spring, $r_1$ is the distance of $M$ from the pivot, $r_2$ is the (varying) distance of $m$ from the pivot, $\theta$ is the angular displacement of the system from the vertical (same for both masses because of the constraint of the spring mass imbued by the rigid rod).

Solving the Euler-Lagrange equations for each variable, we get:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot\theta}\right)- \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta}= (Mr_1^2+mr_2^2)\ddot{\theta} +2mr_2\dot{r_2}\dot\theta + (Mr_1+mr_2)g\sin\theta=0 $$

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot r_2}\right)- \frac{\partial L}{\partial r_2} = m\ddot{r}_2 - mr_2\dot{\theta}^2+mg\cos\theta-k(r_2-l_0)=0$$

Can you reason out the existence of the Coriolis force term?